# Write to cell in google sheets using script on google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a script on a google form that renames files in a destination folder using data from the form submission. I want the google sheet logging the submissions to have a column with the same name as the file. The form submission leaves me with data in A:E, I'd like to add the new column in F. I could potentially use a formula in the sheet to achieve this but -

1. one parameter used for renaming my files is date/time using Utilities.formatDate (now), date/time, which seems to log a time *slightly* different from the time logged as the Timestamp on the google sheet - it seems like a 2 second difference usually, but in the event it's more/less, a formula using the Timestamp in the google sheet might not be accurate
2. form submissions bump down manually-input rows such that the formula doesn't stick to the cell in the newly-added row. I could manually add it, but that's a bit of a pain.

I'd love the sheet to automatically populate with the same output from the below in column F, which would avoid both problems.

var name = FormattedDate + ' - ' + source +' - ' + gender + ' - ' + age
file.setName(name)

Full code below -

```
function onFormSubmit1() {
  var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
  
  var length=form.getResponses().length;
  var gender=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var age=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
  var source=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
  var id=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[3].getResponse();
  var now = new Date();
  var FormattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(now, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
  
  
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  name = file.getName();
  
  var name = FormattedDate + ' - ' + source +' - ' + gender + ' - ' + age 
  file.setName(name);
  
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderidcoderemoved'); 
  
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you your question? 1. In your script, `form.getResponses()[length-1]` is used. In this case, you want to use only the last submitted value. Is my understanding correct? 2. How do you run your script? For example, do you want to run the script with the script editor? Or, want to run it with the OnSubmit trigger?

Comment: Tanaike - yes, using only the last submitted value! And for what I'm trying to accomplish, I'd want to add the file name to the last submitted row.

The script is indeed run OnSubmit right now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Tanaike! I think you are indeed following what I'm trying to do :)! 
I tried the code but it didn't write to column F. I added logs and see this message in the execution log: "You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById". I tried to google to see how to resolve this but there isn't a clear answer (at least, not clear to me :( ). Any chance you know how to resolve this issue to get that portion to write to column F?

Comment: Tanaike - nevermind! I did some more digging and figured out the error. The script did the trick. I had originally had 1000 rows (mostly blank!) in the sheet and it added it to column F in row 1001, so it seemed to be looking for the last *last* row. I just deleted all the empty rows, though... so the form creates a new row that the script now reads as last and adds the name to. Magic! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- Your script is put in the script editor of Google Form.
- Your script is run by OnSubmit trigger.
- When the form is submitted, you want to put the filename to the column "F".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set `ssId` and `sheetName`.

```js
function onFormSubmit1() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var length = form.getResponses().length;
  var gender = form.getResponses()[length - 1].getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var age = form.getResponses()[length - 1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
  var source = form.getResponses()[length - 1].getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
  var id = form.getResponses()[length - 1].getItemResponses()[3].getResponse();

  var now = new Date(); // or form.getResponses()[length - 1].getTimestamp();

  var FormattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(now, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  name = file.getName();
  var name = FormattedDate + ' - ' + source + ' - ' + gender + ' - ' + age
  file.setName(name);
  var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderidcoderemoved');

  // And, I added below script.
  var ssId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID of Spreadsheet that the submitted data is put.
  var sheetName = "###"; // Please set the sheet name of submitted data.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange("F" + sheet.getLastRow()).setValue(name);
}
```

- In this modification, when the script is run, the value of `name` is put to the column "F" of the last submitted row.
- I couldn't understand your script of `var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderidcoderemoved');`. If your showing script is not complete, please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- About the value of `now`, please choose `var now = new Date();` or `var now = form.getResponses()[length - 1].getTimestamp();` for your situation.